# Signing ethereum on blockcypher

Tags: php, json

I'm using Blockcypher API to accept and send ethereum (https://dev.blockcypher.com/eth/#creating-transactions). I've completed all the steps of creating the transaction, I've also signed it, but when I try to push the transaction, I get this error :-

```
Could not compute an address from provided signature: invalid v, r, s values
```

Here's my code :-

```
$s = '{"tx": {"block_height": -1,
    "block_index": 0,
    "hash": "9e1d35246329f2ac42f3d61ea7daa03f7f8d38cd249a232af631453e8faa0ccf",
    "addresses": [
      "0x4bEF3c9f14B1A0633B2224Bfcf24C8Ec079214e1",
      "aad8962fade8687241091bcdb090565f28bd637b"
    ],
    "total": 4200000000000,
    "fees": 861000000000000,
    "size": 43,
    "gas_limit": 21000,
    "gas_price": 41000000000,
    "received": "2016-08-16T15:36:54.568989809Z",
    "ver": 0,
    "double_spend": false,
    "vin_sz": 1,
    "vout_sz": 1,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "sequence": 1,
        "addresses": [
          "0x4bEF3c9f14B1A0633B2224Bfcf24C8Ec079214e1"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "outputs": [
      {
        "value": 4200000000000,
        "addresses": [
          "aad8962fade8687241091bcdb090565f28bd637b"
        ]
      }
    ]}, "tosign": [ "a83f5bea598e0d217a03a2646d6c49edb2e99daf4537b2c09b008df76b77acec" ], "signatures": [ "3045022100d0b005bc83bf8a234cd7326725b26a2fdfdc456dd830c59c18cd2ae849d6d4c60220344efd54daad17c6062bca347ea2bb47a5819b6b162bf69d81bd4a7c4be0e6d2" ]}';

$ch = curl_init('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs/send?token=4751b92ba5c94aecb287b635a0589b6e');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $s);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($s))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: BlockCypher's Developer Advocate here. Honestly hard to tell what went wrong; cryptographic signatures can be an opaque process without seeing the private key (would you be able to share it? or try to reproduce with a separate keypair?). What I can say is that you're setting up the transaction skeleton correctly; based on our two-step process outlined here: https://dev.blockcypher.com/eth/#creating-transactions

With Ethereum, you generate the receiving address/account by generating a Keccack Hash from a public key derived from the signature/message; you can see how this works by checking this code for the resulting public key: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/crypto/secp256k1/secp256.go#L197

I'm guessing the signature was invalid, which resulted in our API failing to generate the appropriate output address. While I can't know exactly what went wrong without the private keys, you may want to double-check that your private key and/or signature were parsed correctly by your signing tool/library, especially if you had to re-encode to a data format for the tool/library you're using.

Also, you may want to try creating/signing a test transaction using addresses generated soley from our API (https://dev.blockcypher.com/eth/#generate-address-endpoint) just using cURL commands. It's not appropriate for large amounts, but the keys generated from this endpoint are already in a hex-encoded format readily usable by our signer tool here: https://github.com/blockcypher/btcutils/tree/master/signer .

Answer (score 0):

Sign the "toSend" value using the signer tool. Then you can transmit the transaction